# woocommerce ad custom button with custom link after add to cart for every product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I googled a long time to find this snippet.

Is there a way to convert the snippet that shows a button in the front end instead of the full link? For example, "BUY NOW". Clicking on this would open the external page in a new browser window. The css for the buttons would come from the basic theme.

```php
// This function gets the value for the the custom fields from the database and adds it to the frontend output function
function wpse_add_custom_link_output() {
    $external_link = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_custom_product_text_field', true);
    $html = '<a href="'.$external_link.'" class="custom-button-class" target="_blank" title="'.__('External product link','woocommerce').'">'.$external_link.'</a>';
    echo $html;
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'wpse_add_custom_link_output', 10, 0 ); 
// This function creates the field in the backend
function wpse_add_custom_link_field(){
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
    // Custom Product Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_custom_product_text_field',
            'placeholder' => __('Paste product link here', 'woocommerce'),
            'label' => __('Custom product link', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip' => 'true'
        )
    );
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'wpse_add_custom_link_field');
// this function saves the link/text field
function wpse_save_custom_link_field($post_id){
    // Custom Product Text Field
    $woocommerce_custom_product_text_field = $_POST['_custom_product_text_field'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field))
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_text_field', 
    esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field));
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wpse_save_custom_link_field');
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the `wpse_add_custom_link_output` callback function this echo the `$html` variable.

So you can simply replace the following line

```php
$html = '<a href="'.$external_link.'" class="custom-button-class" target="_blank" title="'.__('External product link','woocommerce').'">'.$external_link.'</a>';
```

With something like

```php
$html = '<button type="button">BUY NOW</button>';
```